# Split At @ in excel

Tags: excel

BOS@TOR 11/10/2017 07:00PM ET
LA@TB 11/10/2017 07:00PM ET

Above is data I would like to Split at the @ and not get the @ to show up in my columns.
The First is Away and the Second is Home.

```
=LEFT(L2,FIND("@",L2)-1)
=RIGHT(L2,FIND("@",L2)*1)
```

It Returns  Home: TOR, Away: BOS. Perfect! Same With LA AND TB. But If its BOS@LA
it will return HOME @LA and ROAD BOS. How can I just remove the @ regardless of the number of Characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing what `=RIGHT(L2,FIND("@",L2)-1)` is doing (I'm assuming you typo-ed on this formula seeing as the one in your question cannot give you the results you mention). `FIND("@",L2)` gets the position of the first `@` in the string, And `RIGHT` takes the *n*th characters from the right of the supplied string. You will notice your current formula will only work if the @ is at a position gives a number which is the same length plus one as the part you want to get. i.e. `BOS@TOR` has @ at 4th position, and `TOR` is 3 characters long, and `LA@TB` has @ at 3rd position, and `TB` is 2 characters long.

Proposed solutions:

**Using Formula**

```
=MID(L2,FIND("@",L2)+1,LEN(L2))
```

`MID` is a formula similar to `LEFT` and `RIGHT`, except it has one additional parameter required; the length of the string. `FIND("@",L2)+1` gets the position of the next character after the first `@`, and the length of the string can be anything at least equal to the length of the string you want to get (if it's larger, it's still fine).

The below is another option that uses `SUBSTITUTE`, assuming that `M2` is where the HOME value is stored:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(L2,M2&"@","",1)
```

This instead takes the original text and removes the home value at the accompanying `@` sign with a blank. The last parameter indicates that it removes only the first instance of "Home+@" (if you know there can be only one, you can ignore the last parameter completely so that the formula becomes `=SUBSTITUTE(L2,M2&"@","")`)

**Using Text to Column**

Select the column, and click the option 'Text to Columns' in the Data tab, pick 'Delimited' and click next:

[image]

Uncheck everything, then check the last option 'Other', type `@` in the box, then next:

[image]

Click on finish:

[image]

Note: this method overwrites the original texts, so if you want to keep them, make a copy of the text in a new column first, and split on that column.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, Mid worked Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with `=RIGHT(L2,FIND("@",L2))` (the "multiply by one" is superfluous, by the way) when you have something like:

```
BIGSTRING@X
```

is that the position of the `@` depends on the length of `BIGSTRING` rather than `X`. The position of the `@` is ten and the rightmost ten characters of `BIGSTRING@X` are *not* `X` but rather `IGSTRING@X`.

This means it will work for something like `XYZZY@PLUGH` (same size on either side of the `@`) but *not* `NINECHARS@FOUR` (with different sizes).

The first calculation is correct as-is. For the second calculation, you should remove the size of `BIGSTRING@` to get the desired number of characters to extract on the right:

```
=RIGHT(L2,LEN(L2)-FIND("@",L2))
```

Had Excel been smart enough to offer the variant of the `MID` formula function where a missing length meant "take remainder of string" (VBA has it), you could have also used `=MID(L2,FIND("@",L2)+1)`.

But, since formula `MID` appears to need the length, I'd just opt for the `RIGHT` variant as above.

Comment: Not being an Excel wiz it sounds like I'm kind of SOL?

Comment: @MichaelTJohnson, assuming that means "sh*t outta luck", not at all. Just use the `right` variant I provided in my answer and it will correctly extract the appropriately sized right part of the string. I've tested that both with `BIGSTRING@X` and `BOS@LA` successfully. For `BOS@LA`, length is six, subtract position of `@` which is four, that gives two, and the righmost two characters are `LA`. Voila!

Comment: Thank you for your time paxdiablo